# mysql/mariadb replication with proxy

Tags: replication, mariadb, mysql-proxy

I have a standard master-slave replication for MariaDB to sync one database (master) to multiple slaves. One of the slaves lives behind a proxy, so I need to proxy the replication request to the proxy and from the proxy to the master.

Can I use the `proxy_protocol_networks` parameter to proxy the requests? Can I proxy replications requests?

Example:

- master: 192.168.1.1
- slave: 172.16.1.20 
  mysqld.cnf: `proxy_protocol_networks= "172.16.1.1"`
- proxy: 172.16.1.1

slave ---> proxy ----> master

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can proxy replication requests if the proxy is configured to speak the proxy protocol to the master.

Comment: Is this also possible with a proxy of defined ports? The proxy only allow traffic on port 80/443 and my master listens on port 3306.
So the traffic goes like this.
172.16.1.20 --> 172.16.1.1:443 --> 192.168.1.1:3306

Comment: How to configure the proxy parameter for the slave?

Comment: The slave doesn't need any configuration apart from connecting to the proxy server.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your proxy information including configuration. Reference to [proxy protocol](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#5.1-accept-proxy). MariaDB replicas (slaves) cannot speak to HTTP proxies which you may be assuming.